# Saving GET result in a text file ends up in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I've been trying to save a String I get from a GET request into a text file. For some reason, it ends up in an infinite loop and if I don't use `created()`, it doesn't work at all, `story` just stays empty.

```
<div id="app">
    <p>{{story}}</p>
    <a id="link" v-bind:href="url" target="_blank" download="file.txt">Download</a>
</div>

<script>
    var str = {
        data: function () {
        return {
          story: '',
          file: null,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async getStory(id) {
          var req = 'http://localhost:8080/api/story/' + id
          try {
            const response = await axios.get(req);
            return response.data.story;
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
          }
          return false;
        },
        async getLetter() {
          var story = await this.getStory(this.$route.params.id);
          this.story = letter;
        },
        textFile() {
          var data = [];
          console.log(this.story);
          data.push(this.story);
          var properties = {
            type: 'text/plain'
          };
          try {
            this.file = new File(data, "file.txt", properties);
          } catch (e) {
            this.file = new Blob(data, properties);
          }
          this.url = URL.createObjectURL(this.file);
        }
      },
      created() {
        this.getLetter();
      },
      updated() {
        this.textFile();
      }
    }
</script>
```

Is it even wise to use the HTML5 feature to save files?

Comment: `this.story = letter;` Where is `letter` defined?

Comment: `infinite loop` ... can't see any form of loop in your code - describe this loop, which part of your code is "looping" as far as you can tell?

Comment: this.story = story @StephenThomas

Comment: @Jaromandax I can't even tell because my browser just starts freezing and asks me to stop the script.

Comment: The reason why your story is always null is that you already draw the {{story}} when the request is still running, you can't use async wait here. But I dun think this is the reason why browser freezed. Can you add some break point, and take a look which line causes you trouble?

Comment: It's weird, removing {{letter}} stops the freezing but then the textfile contains the html source instead of the letter

Answer (score 0):

Axios is a promise-base HTTP API, so removing the async/await will do

```
getStory(id) {
      return new Promise((res, rej) => {
          var req = 'http://localhost:8080/api/story/' + id
          axios.get(req).then((response) => {
              res(response.data.story);
           }).catch((err) => {
              rej(err);
           });
      })
    },
    getLetter() {
      var story = this.getStory(this.$route.params.id);
      this.story = letter;
    }
```

One more thing, there is loop so there is no infinite loop happening. Instead, the request is not finish.

Comment: But then, story returns "Promise { <state>: "pending" }"

Comment: If that is so, it must be a problem with your API (the url)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the following code below see

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
 data () {
    return {
      story:"",
      url:"",
     
    }
  },
  created(){
 this.getLetter();
  },
  methods: {

        getStory:function(id) {
             var req = 'http://localhost/website-one-pages/slipt.php?id=' + id;
     axios.get(req).then((response) => {
                this.story = response.data;
                
                //set download
                var data = [];
                data.push(this.story);
                var properties = {
               type: 'text/plain'
             };
             try {
               this.file = new File(data, "file.txt", properties);
             } catch (e) {
               this.file = new Blob(data, properties);
             }
             this.url = URL.createObjectURL(this.file);
             //end set download

             }).catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error);
              });
        },
        getLetter() {
          var id =2;//example id=2 
          this.getStory(id);
        },
    }
    
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <p>{{story}}</p>
   
    <a id="link" v-bind:href="url" target="_blank" download="file.txt">Download</a>
```

Comment: This way it actually works. A million thanks! Sadly I can't upvote yet.